# Can we use CMake foreach in template source file?

Tags: c, cmake

For unit testing my functions, i have auto-generated the name, like it:

test_implode
test_range

into a CMake variable.

I want to call all automatically in C.
I also used config file (.in.c) in CMake

```
set(CONFIG configuration)
configure_file(${CONFIG}.in.c ${CONFIG}.c)
set(CONFIG_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CONFIG}.c)
```

But the name of the function are just in a List in CMake, the C syntax is not valid. I could generate a variable in CMake with appropriate syntax, but generating output in config file would let the CMake source file clean and could be possibly very powerful.

Concretly, what I would like to do is that (imaginary syntax):

```
#include "tests.h"

void all_tests() {

    void(*tests)()[] = {
    @FOREACH(FUNC FUNCTIONS)@
        test_@FUNC@,
    @ENDFOREACH()@
        NULL
    };

    void(*test_function)() = tests[0];

    while(test_function) {
        test_function();
        test_function++;
    }
}
```

Similarly to blade or php.
Can I use CMake as a scripting language (or a foreach) or is it mandatory to put this in the CMake source file and store it into a variable ?

What I currently do, which is acceptable, works. But I'm learning and I would like to know if it's still possible or not

```
foreach(PHP_FUNCTION ${PHP_FUNCTIONS})
  list(APPEND GENERATED_C_CODE_RUN_TEST "\n\ttest_${PHP_FUNCTION}()")
endforeach()

set(GENERATED_C_CODE_RUN_TEST "${GENERATED_C_CODE_RUN_TEST};")
set(CONFIG configuration)
configure_file(${CONFIG}.in.c ${CONFIG}.c)
set(CONFIG_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CONFIG}.c)
add_executable(...);
```

```
#include "tests.h"

void all_tests() {

    @GENERATED_C_CODE_RUN_TEST@
}
```

Comment: CMake template engine, used for `configure_file` isn't very powerful. Everything which it support is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/configure_file.html). As you can see, is has no "foreach" functionality. So, if you don't want to use another template engine (non-CMake one), you need to resort to constructing intermediate variables. BTW, CMake also do such things in some of its own modules. See e.g. [CheckTypeSize.c.in](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CheckTypeSize.c.in) or other `.in` files in `Modules/` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to append the `test_` prefix to each test name in a list, then use [`list(JOIN ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#join) to construct a string representing a comma-separated list (which is valid C syntax).

```
list(APPEND PHP_FUNCTIONS
    func1
    func2
    func3
)

# Append the 'test_' prefix to each test function name.
foreach(PHP_FUNCTION ${PHP_FUNCTIONS})
    list(APPEND FUNCTION_NAMES_LIST "test_${PHP_FUNCTION}")
endforeach()
message(STATUS "FUNCTION_NAMES_LIST: ${FUNCTION_NAMES_LIST}")

# Construct a comma-separated string from the list.
list(JOIN FUNCTION_NAMES_LIST "," FUNCTION_NAMES_STRING)
message(STATUS "FUNCTION_NAMES_STRING: ${FUNCTION_NAMES_STRING}")
```

This prints the following:

```
FUNCTION_NAMES_LIST: test_func1;test_func2;test_func3
FUNCTION_NAMES_STRING: test_func1,test_func2,test_func3
```

Then, you can modify your `configuration.in.c` file so only one variable needs to be substituted:

```
void all_tests() {

    void(*tests)()[] = {
        @FUNCTION_NAMES_STRING@,
        NULL
    };

    void(*test_function)() = tests[0];

    while(test_function) {
        test_function();
        test_function++;
    }
}
```

You can play around with the "glue" or separator string used to join the CMake list together. In my example, I used `","` but you can use `", "` or `",\n\t"` to make the resultant C code more visually pleasing. CMake [`list()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) (and [`string()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html)) have lots of manipulation options to play around with, so I encourage you to check them out.